# How much more secure is $c = mg_1^r + g_2(g_1(g_1^r-1)/(g_1-1)) \mod p$ compared to just $c = mg_1^r \mod p$ (dis. log), all known but $r$?

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, elgamal-encryption, attack, known-plaintext-attack

To encode a message $m$ to a cipher $c$ you can use the only hard solvable problem of computing the discrete logarithm with a generator $g$ in base over a prime $p$.

$c = mg_1^r$ mod p

If an attacker want to derive $r$ he can use e.g. the Baby-step giant-step algorithm. He can solve this in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{p})$.
I'm looking for a way to make it harder to reduce the size of $p$ and still be safe.

### Are there any records about solving something like this:

$c = mg_1^r + g_2\frac{g_1(g_1^r-1)}{g_1-1} \mod p$

Or do you know any? Would it (significantly) increase the solve time $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{p})$?

The potential attacker has the source code and so he knows $g_1, g_2$ and $p$. So if he picks a known $m$ and $r$ he can also compute $c$. In my usage scenario each computed $c$ can be used as $m$ to compute the next $c$. So the main aspect is not to encode a message. I'm looking for a way to make the computation of r as hard as possible for a given $m$ and $c$. That means the attacker has by default a given $m$ and some $c$'s. He should not be able to compute the respective $r$'s which allows him to compute those $c$'s out of the $m$. And if he somehow managed to compute $r$ for a $m$ to get $c$ it should not be easier if $m$ or $c$ changes.

---

### Derivation of formula:

If you use $+$ instead of $*$ operator you can encode like:

$c_1 = m+g_2 \mod p$

$c_2 = m+g_2+g_2\mod p$

so for $c_r$ you can shorten it with multiplication by r

$c_r = m+rg_2\mod p$

But this can easy be solved with computing $g_2^{-1}$ with e.g. eucl. algorithm.

But how about a combination with $*$ operator?

$c_1 = (m+g_2)*g_1\mod p$

$c_2 = ((m+g_2)*g_1+g_2)*g_1 = mg_1^2+g_2g_1^2+g_2g_1\mod p$

$c_3 = mg_1^3+g_2g_1^3+g_2g_1^2+g_2g_1\mod p$

so for $c_r$

$c_r = m*g_1^r + g_2*\sum_{i=1}^r g_1^i \mod p$

$c_R = mg_1^r + g_2\frac{g_1(g_1^r-1)}{g_1-1} \mod p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attacker knows everything (including $m$) except for $r$, he can rewrite it to:

$$g_1^r = (c + g_1 g_2 (g_1 - 1)^{-1}) ( m + g_1 g_2( g_1 - 1)^{-1})^{-1} \pmod{p}$$

He knows everything on the RHS, and so it's a simple discrete log problem.

BTW: for the $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ group, there are much faster attacks than Baby-step-Giant-step

Comment: @J.Doe: perhaps use an elliptic curve group instead?

Comment: oh dear, how could I not see that. Thanks for quick response. Need to think about another way to solve it. Or do you or anyone know a better way?

Comment: use case need to be in 3 dimension. With elliptic curves I would miss the factorization (or at least I think so -> will create new question). As long there is no way to have some single number and 3 generator (one for each ellip. curve) which can be used on it, including no internal representation of each dimension because attacker can see source code.